# Error encoding when parsing response from REST request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, restsharp

Context: I use Selenium for parsing content at http://bizhub.vn/tech/start-up-cvn-loyalty-receives-vnd11-billion-investment_318377.html , then get content of news post, then summary to 4 sentences use API from meaningcloud.com (text summarization services).

I am using .NET 5.0.100-preview.8.20417.9 , ASP.NET Core Web API 5,  I have

File `SysUtil.cs`

```cs
using System;

namespace bizhubdotvn_tech.Controllers
{
    public class SysUtil
    {
        public static String StringEncodingConvert(String strText, String strSrcEncoding, String strDestEncoding)
        {
            System.Text.Encoding srcEnc = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(strSrcEncoding);
            System.Text.Encoding destEnc = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(strDestEncoding);
            byte[] bData = srcEnc.GetBytes(strText);
            byte[] bResult = System.Text.Encoding.Convert(srcEnc, destEnc, bData);
            return destEnc.GetString(bResult);
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
        public static string SummaryText(string newsContent)
        {
            var client = new RestClient("https://api.meaningcloud.com/summarization-1.0");
            client.Timeout = -1;
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.AddParameter("key", "25870359b682ec3c93f9becd850eb442");
            request.AddParameter("txt", JsonEncodedText.Encode(newsContent));
            request.AddParameter("sentences", 4);
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            var mm = JObject.Parse(response.Content);
            string raw_string = (string)mm["summary"];
            //FIXME: sinh ra các ký tự lạ.
            string foo2 = SysUtil.StringEncodingConvert(raw_string, "Windows-1251", "UTF-8");
            Console.WriteLine("summary4 = " + foo2);
            return foo2;
        }
```

`response.Content` =

```
"{\"status\":{\"code\":\"0\",\"msg\":\"OK\",\"credits\":\"1\",\"remaining_credits\":\"19756\"},\"summary\":\"NextPay Joint Stock Company on Monday announced it had invested VND11 billion (US$473,000) in CNV Loyalty.Established at the end of 2017, CNV Loyalty creates customer care applications for businesses.Nguyen Tuan Phu, founder cum CEO of CNV Loyalty said: \\\\u201CWith only the cost of VND50 - 150 million, significantly lower than building a customer care system in a traditional way, Loyalty designs a customised application for the business with its own brand to interact directly with customers. In particular, the rate of accessing customers accurately up to 95 per cent.\\\\u201DThe start-up has received an investment of VND11 billion from NextPay and Next100 - investment fund from Nguyen Hoa Binh after two months of an appraisal.Nguyen Huu Tuat, CEO of NextPay said: \\\\u201CWe are living in a digital economy whose main form is the app economy. [...] CNV Loyalty is a solution to help brands always present directly, interact directly, understand their customers directly at a zero cost. [...] The investment of NextPay will help CNV Loyalty to invest more deeply in technology and products.With the market heavily influenced by COVID-19, Vietnamese start-ups still developing and receiving investment from domestic investors without being dependent on venture capital abroad is a great encouragement to Viet Nam\\\\u0027s start-up community.\"}"
```

`foo2` =

```
"NextPay Joint Stock Company on Monday announced it had invested VND11 billion (US$473,000) in CNV Loyalty.Established at the end of 2017, CNV Loyalty creates customer care applications for businesses.Nguyen Tuan Phu, founder cum CEO of CNV Loyalty said: \\u201CWith only the cost of VND50 - 150 million, significantly lower than building a customer care system in a traditional way, Loyalty designs a customised application for the business with its own brand to interact directly with customers. In particular, the rate of accessing customers accurately up to 95 per cent.\\u201DThe start-up has received an investment of VND11 billion from NextPay and Next100 - investment fund from Nguyen Hoa Binh after two months of an appraisal.Nguyen Huu Tuat, CEO of NextPay said: \\u201CWe are living in a digital economy whose main form is the app economy. [...] CNV Loyalty is a solution to help brands always present directly, interact directly, understand their customers directly at a zero cost. [...] The investment of NextPay will help CNV Loyalty to invest more deeply in technology and products.With the market heavily influenced by COVID-19, Vietnamese start-ups still developing and receiving investment from domestic investors without being dependent on venture capital abroad is a great encouragement to Viet Nam\\u0027s start-up community."
```

[image]

How to resolve problem at `\\u201C` (globally, consider this type of character, not only one specific character)?

Comment: The problem is it was encoded wrong. It should be stored in your JSON like this: `...encouragement to Viet Nam\u0027s start-up com...` Something went in and added too many back-slashes to that `\u` value. If you didn't derive that data, then you are left to write a kludge to fix the data.

Comment: Can you send the exact URL you were using that got you that data? The one you added to your question is not producing the same results.

Comment: full source code is very long, include Selenium, WebDriver, WebElement parsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this may be the post-processing you are doing on the object returned. You shouldn't have to do any of that. This could also be the `RestClient` you are using. There is no reason to use `RestClient`. You can use `HttpClient` to do everything and anything you'd ever need with the HTTP prototcol.

I went and signed up for a key and tried it and it worked just fine as is without having to "re-encode" the data. Here is my implementation:

```
private static readonly HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();

private sealed class MeaningResponseModel
{
    [JsonProperty("summary")]
    public string Summary { get; set; }
}

private static async Task<MeaningResponseModel> GetMeaningfulDataAsync(
    string key, int sentences, Uri uri)
{
    var queryString = $"key={key}&sentences={sentences}" +
        $"&url={WebUtility.UrlEncode(uri.ToString())}";

    using (var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post,
        new UriBuilder("https://api.meaningcloud.com/summarization-1.0")
    {
        Query = queryString
    }.Uri))
    {
        using (var res = await _httpClient.SendAsync(req))
        {
            res.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            using(var s = await res.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
            using(var sr = new StreamReader(s))
            using(var jtr = new JsonTextReader(sr))
            {
                return new JsonSerializer().Deserialize<MeaningResponseModel>(jtr);
            }
        }
    }
}

private async Task TestThis()
{
    var test = await GetMeaningfulDataAsync(
        "YOUR KEY HERE",
        20,
        new Uri("http://bizhub.vn/tech/start-up-cvn-loyalty-receives-vnd11-billion-investment_318377.html"));

    Console.WriteLine(test.Summary);
}
```

The output:

[image: working result]

Comment: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1328316/92071228-63204700-edd8-11ea-83e6-e1414eeccf46.png help me resolve this ambigous

Comment: @DoNhuVy -- You want the `Newtonsoft.Json` one

Answer (score 1):

Base on [the answer of Andy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63716602/3728901)

```cs
private static readonly HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();

private sealed class MeaningResponseModel
{
    [JsonProperty("summary")]
    public string Summary { get; set; }
}

private static async Task<MeaningResponseModel> GetMeaningfulDataAsync(string key, int sentences, string content)
{
    var queryString = $"key={key}&sentences={sentences}&txt={content}";
    using (var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, new UriBuilder("https://api.meaningcloud.com/summarization-1.0") { Query = queryString }.Uri))
    {
        using (var res = await _httpClient.SendAsync(req))
        {
            res.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            using (var s = await res.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(s))
            using (var jtr = new JsonTextReader(sr))
            {
                return new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer().Deserialize<MeaningResponseModel>(jtr);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

when using:

```cs
// Lấy summary 4 câu.
var temp = await GetMeaningfulDataAsync("25870359b682ec3c93f9becd850eb442", 4, contentAfterTrim);
string summary4 = temp.Summary;
summary4 = summary4.Replace("[...] ", "");
news.Summary4 = summary4;
Console.WriteLine("summary4 = " + summary4);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to replace the special characters like

> \u201c

Nick van Esch posted an answer about the same in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2205826/8516044) which might help you.

Comment: That's not the problem he/she is having.

Comment: I think the issue is when you try to add special character in C# string than you need to append \ in order to support it. May be I am wrong and misunderstood the question.

Comment: Oh, no. Don't do like the answer.