# String.Replace() for quotation marks

Tags: vb.net, replace

I am trying to run the following line of code to replace the Microsoft Word quotes with ones our database can store. I need to work around users copying strings from Microsoft Word into my textareas.

instrText = instrText.Replace("“", """).Replace("”", """)

I am getting syntax errors for the number of arguments.

[image]

I have tried character escapes and a couple other ways of formatting the arguments with no luck.

Comment: `instrText = instrText.Replace(""“", """")`

Comment: I have tried this. I don't get syntax errors but it doesn't replace the double quote.

Comment: Can you encode / compress / base64 the original text? It seems safer.

Comment: Have you considered using a database column of type `NVARCHAR` to store the data? (Or the equivalent Unicode type in your database.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This changes the 'smart' quotes from word,

```
    'non standard quotes
    Dim Squotes() As Char = {ChrW(8216), ChrW(8217)} 'single
    Dim Dquotes() As Char = {ChrW(8220), ChrW(8221)} 'double

    'build test string
    Dim s As String = ""
    For x As Integer = 0 To Squotes.Length - 1
        s &= x.ToString & Squotes(x) & ", "
    Next
    For x As Integer = 0 To Dquotes.Length - 1
        s &= (x + Squotes.Length).ToString & Dquotes(x) & ", "
    Next

    'replace
    For Each c As Char In Squotes
        s = s.Replace(c, "'"c)
    Next

    For Each c As Char In Dquotes
        s = s.Replace(c, ControlChars.Quote)
    Next
```

Comment: I would like to keep it with the string.replace() if possible because I have other characters I am replacing with that statement. I removed them for the post to keep it simpler and they aren't the ones giving me issues.

Comment: What?  Word has different start and end quote marks for both the single and double smart quotes so you'll need to do multiple replacements, so I don't know what your first statement means.

Comment: This is the full line I'm trying to run. Everything in there works except for the double quotes. That is why I am trying to keep it all in the same line of code if I can and not have a different statement to handle to double quotes.

Comment: instrText = instrText.Replace("–", "-").Replace("•", "-").Replace("…", ".").Replace("‘", "'").Replace("’", "'").Replace("“", """).Replace("”", """)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I did get this to work just replacing the string values for the double quotes with the ChrW values in my string.replace() methods.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
Private Function CleanInput(input As String) As String
    DisplayUnicode(input)
    '8216 = &H2018  - left single-quote
    '8217 = &H2019  - right single-quote
    '8220 = &H201C  - left double-quote
    '8221 = &H201D  - right double-quote

    'Return input.Replace(ChrW(&H2018), Chr(39)).Replace(ChrW(&H2019), Chr(39)).Replace(ChrW(&H201C), Chr(34)).Replace(ChrW(&H201D), Chr(34))
    Return input.Replace(ChrW(8216), Chr(39)).Replace(ChrW(8217), Chr(39)).Replace(ChrW(8220), Chr(34)).Replace(ChrW(8221), Chr(34))
End Function

Private Sub DisplayUnicode(input As String)
    For i As Integer = 0 To input.Length - 1
        Dim lngUnicode As Long = AscW(input(i))

        If lngUnicode < 0 Then

            lngUnicode = 65536 + lngUnicode
        End If

        Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("char: {0} Unicode: {1}", input(i).ToString(), lngUnicode.ToString()))
    Next

    Debug.WriteLine("")
End Sub
```

**Usage**:

```
 Dim cleaned As String = CleanInput(TextBoxInput.Text)
```

**Resources**:

- [ASCII table](https://www.asciitable.com/)
- [C# How to replace Microsoft's Smart Quotes with straight quotation marks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334850/c-sharp-how-to-replace-microsofts-smart-quotes-with-straight-quotation-marks)
- [How to represent Unicode character in VB.Net String literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144053/how-to-represent-unicode-character-in-vb-net-string-literal)

**Note**: Also used `Character Map` in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You have a solution that works above, but in keeping with your original form:

```vb
instrText = instrText.Replace(ChrW(8220), """"c).Replace(ChrW(8221), """"c)
```